# iOS 9 deprecation warnings while targetting iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios9, deprecated

I have an app that needs to support iOS 7, but I'd like to have the deprecation warnings as if I was targeting iOS 9. Is there any way I can get them without changing my target to iOS 9?

Comment: Have you tried to change compile SDK?

Comment: Why do you want deprecation warnings? You can keep using the deprecated class/method without issue. The much bigger worry is accidentally using an iOS 8 or 9 API while under iOS 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get them without changing my target to iOS 9?

None that I know of, but you can certainly change your target to iOS 9 to get the warnings, and then change back to iOS 7. That should be enough to let you know what issues in your code will need to be updated when you're preparing to drop iOS 7 support.

Comment: But there's no point to this now. If the OP wants to support iOS 7+ now, there is no benefit to seeing deprecation warnings now. I wish the OP would explain their goal.

Comment: OP probably isn't planning to support 7 forever, and looking at deprecation warnings is a quick way to assess work required to modernize the code.

Comment: Correct @Caleb, and it's about bringing the cost of supporting iOS 7 out - and not maintaining old habits that result in deprecated code